# mvc bootstrap editor template add two label for Html.Editorformodel()

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, templates, editor

im using mvc 4 and i just installed bootstrap editor templates via nuget packet

```
PM> Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.templates
```

the problem is when i use Html.editorformodel() it will generate two same label for each field.
for example first label is some thing like:

```
<div class="editor-label"><label for="Parent_CodeMeli">کد ملی ولی</label></div>
```

and second one is like :

```
<div class="editor-field">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label" for="Parent_CodeMeli">کد ملی ولی</label>
<div class="controls">
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="کد ملی ولی را وارد کنید"         id="Parent_CodeMeli" name="Parent.CodeMeli" type="text" value="">
     <span class="field-validation-valid help-block" data-valmsg-for="Parent.CodeMeli" data- valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
</div>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Parent.CodeMeli" data-valmsg- replace="true"></span></div>
```

my guess is that it will generate first one when it want to use editor template for model field and second one is generated when use editor for string.
**how can i remove first label? the one that make editor-label?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found something, i delete labelfor in string editor template.

```
<div class="form-group@(Html.ValidationErrorFor(m => m, " has-error"))">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m, new { @class = "control-label" })
<div class="controls">
    @Html.TextBox(
        "",
        ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
        htmlAttributes)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m, null, new { @class = "help-block" })
</div>
</div>
```

and use seprate html.labelfor whenever i use editorfor some string field